# Applying gsub to various columns

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

What is the most efficient way to apply `gsub` to various columns?
The following does not work

```
x1=c("10%","20%","30%")
x2=c("60%","50%","40%")
x3 = c(1,2,3)
x = data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
per_col = c(1,2)
x = gsub("%","",x[,per_col])
```

How can I most efficiently drop the "%" sign in specified columns.
Can I apply it to the whole dataframe? This would be useful in the case where I don't know where the percentage columns are.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `apply` to apply it to the whole data.frame

```
apply(x, 2, function(y) as.numeric(gsub("%", "", y)))
     x1 x2 x3
[1,] 10 60  1
[2,] 20 50  2
[3,] 30 40  3
```

Comment: Warning: `apply()` returns a matrix and not a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 13):

Or, you could try the `lapply` solution:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(x, function(y) gsub("%", "", y)))

  x1 x2 x3
1 10 60  1
2 20 50  2
3 30 40  3
```

Comment: in addition to the second question, the original posts asked how gsub could be applied to "specified columns".  Care to comment on how to make gsub apply to only columns specified rather than all columns?

Comment: @WBarker: as.data.frame(lapply(x[c('x1','x2')], function(y) gsub("%", "", y)))  ?  Admittedly,. needs a bit of work to update the existing columns.

Comment: This seems to return a column of class "list" (each item a list length one containing the string result).  Is there any way to return a column of the original character class

Answer (score 3):

The first answer works but be careful if you are using `data.frame` with string: the @docendo discimus's answer will return `NAs`.

If you want to keep the content of your column as string just remove the `as.numeric` and convert your table into a data frame after :

```
as.data.frame(apply(x, 2, function(y) as.numeric(gsub("%", "", y))))
     x1 x2 x3
[1,] 10 60  1
[2,] 20 50  2
[3,] 30 40  3
```

Comment: This is also in a  way the solution proposed @info_seekeR

Answer (score 2):

We can `unlist` `per_col` columns, remove "`%`" symbol and convert it into numeric.

```
x[per_col] <- as.numeric(gsub("%","", unlist(x[per_col])))
#In this case using sub would be enough too as we have only 1 % symbol to replace
#x[per_col] <- as.numeric(sub("%","", unlist(x[per_col])))

x
#  x1 x2 x3
#1 10 60  1
#2 20 50  2
#3 30 40  3
```

Answer (score 1):

To add on [docendo discimus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23831351), an extension with non-adjacent columns and returning a `data.frame`:

```
x1 <- c("10%", "20%", "30%")
x2 <- c("60%", "50%", "40%")
x3 <- c(1, 2, 3)
x4 <- c("60%", "50%", "40%")

x <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4)

x[, c(1:2, 4)] <- as.data.frame(apply(x[,c(1:2, 4)], 2,
                                         function(x) {
                                           as.numeric(gsub("%", "", x))}
))

> x
  x1 x2 x3 x4
1 10 60  1 60
2 20 50  2 50
3 30 40  3 40

> class(x)
[1] "data.frame"
```